# Android oAuth working on Android 2.2. but does not work on Android 4.0.

Tags: android, oauth

I'm using oAuth to perform some authentication.

I try to use given API for that, and I quite do not understand what is going on.

On Android device using Android 2.2. I get webview where I enter username and password, and receive token, and perform login.

Same code, same calls on Android 4.0 returns "null" and I can't login to service.

I log all my details needed, and method that should get the Token returns null. Have no idea where to log, what to log, what to check.

```
11-08 14:16:19.576: W/Globals.Hyves.CONSUMER_KEY(946): 
11-08 14:16:19.576: W/Globals.Hyves.CONSUMER_SECRET(946): 
11-08 14:16:19.576: W/Globals.Hyves.REQTOKEN_LINK(946): http://data.hyves-api.nl/?strict_oauth_spec_response=true&methods=users.get,friends.get,wwws.create&ha_method=auth.requesttoken&ha_version=2.1
11-08 14:16:19.576: W/Globals.Hyves.REQACCESSTOKEN_LINK(946): http://data.hyves-api.nl/?strict_oauth_spec_response=true&ha_method=auth.accesstoken&ha_version=2.1
11-08 14:16:19.576: W/Globals.Hyves.AUTHORIZATION_LINK(946): http://www.hyves.nl/api/authorize/
11-08 14:16:19.681: W/Consumer(946): oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer@416263a0
11-08 14:16:19.710: W/Provider(946): oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider@41624ad0
11-08 14:16:19.710: W/Globals.Hyves.REDIRECT_URI(946): connect://success
11-08 14:16:20.186: W/System.err(946): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null
11-08 14:16:20.206: W/System.err(946):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
```

Does anyone know if there is difference between some default page coding, or something that is significantly different and may cause that this works on one android and it does not work on the other.

This is the line I call:

```
String authUrl = SignpostHandler.retrieveRequestTokenWithSignpost(provider, consumer, Globals.Hyves.REDIRECT_URI);
```

I do have provider and consumer as you can see in Log

Answer (score 0):

I think you do http get/post request without AsyncTask.

I think,this is StrictMode problem. [Here information about StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)

try this in AsyncTask. [Here informaton about AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)